# What happened to the 'Related' sidebar?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed

Previously, whenever I asked a question, there used to be a 'Related' tab on the right side. It used to display links to a lot of related posts. Now, I cannot see the tab 'Related' anymore. It was useful to track the related posts. Has there been a recent change on the site regarding this or is it a temporary problem?

Comment: Was a [known problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350569/263383) that was fixed, but apparently is resurfacing now.

Comment: Wasn't this asked recently on physics meta? Did the user delete the question?

Comment: @BioPhysicist Yes, it was deleted. That problem was temporarily fixed. At that time I could see the 'Related' tag with no posts under it. Now I can't even see the 'Related' tag.

Comment: This question belongs on the mother meta site.

Comment: I've just posted a comment on the mother meta linking this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350569/

Comment: There's also a more recent question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352855/816175